# AWS Glue - Crawler skipping some folder in S3

Tags: aws-glue, aws-iot

I have a crawler in AWS Glue to maintain the data catalog table for an AWS S3 database from an IoT device measuring temperature and humidity.

The settings of the crawler are as follows:

Crawl new sub-folders only.
Sample only a subset of files: 1.

I've noticed that the crawler occasionally misses some folders, but it updates correctly after a few hours. During that period, it shows no data (even though the data appears in S3). The missing folders/data are only crawled when I re-run the crawler with the "crawl all folders" setting.

Is there any specific setting on the crawler that could be causing this issue? Any ideas?"

the crawler will not miss or skip folder if i set Crawl all folder each time, but it will cause usage of DPU hour to high.